# ¿Cómo compruebo que un elemento de un array es nulo=

Tags: java, array, recursión, null, bluej

estoy practicando recursividad en java y quiero hacer un método que me devuelva la posición del primer elemento no nulo de un array de enteros, pero no me deja usar el comparador "!=".
El código es:

```
public static int primerNoNulo(int[] v, int ini){
    if(v[ini] != null){
        return ini;
    }else{
        return primerNoNulo(v, ini + 1);
    }
  }
```

Como podéis ver, el caso general es cuando el elemento "v[i]" es "null", por eso llamo al método y le sumo 1 a i. El caso base es cuando "v[i]" es diferente de "null", que en este caso devuelvo "i" porque es la posición. Como he mencionado, usando el operador "!=" salta un error, pero no comprendo por qué ya que usando iteración sí que me dejaba ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Una variable cuyo tipo sea primitivo (int, long, char, boolean, double,,,) nunca puede valer null. Sólo las variables que "apuntan" a objetos pueden tener ese valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En java existen 2 tipos de variables primitivos y objetos, la variables primitivas se identifican porque su nombre se escribe en minúscula, por ejemplo para la variable primitiva `int` existe su contraparte objeto o envoltorio `Integer`, las variables primitivas no pueden ser `null` para el caso de un array de `int` se inicializara con zero para cada variable primitiva.

Java se diseño así ya que inicialmente se pensaba en poder ejecutar la JVM en dispositivos electrónicos de bajo consumo, a nivel de la JVM un `Integer` es más costoso de obtener porque un Objeto es una referencia en memoria, la JVM debe preguntarle primero la referencia al objeto y después buscarla en la memoria por eso si un objeto no se encuentra en memoria es `null`, mientras que un primitivo contiene el valor directamente, esto en el día a día no es relevante amenos que desarrolles aplicaciones que requieran gran eficiencia y velocidad de ejecución donde cada milisegundo cuenta.

Comment: Ya entiendo lo que me ha pasado, cuando usaba la iteración usaba arrays de tipo referencia, por lo que no había problemas con null. Gracias.